# JApplet Won't Open With Console Program

Tags: java, applet, logic, implementation

Given my code below how can I make the paint applet open up when I run the main code? I thought extends would do the trick but nothing has come up. I can't get the program to execute one body part at a time. I don't have enough time, but at the very least I would like it to show the hangman drawing as soon as the main is executed.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class HangmanLogic extends HangmanGuy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0;
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a 4 or 5 letter word and the computer will play hangman against you!");



         String word = in.nextLine();


         char[] letter = word.toCharArray();


         for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
                 letter[i] = 'a';
         }


         for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
             for (int j = 48; j < 122; j++) {
                            count++;
                         if (letter[i] == word.charAt(i)) { 
                                 break; 
                         } else {
                                 letter[i] = (char)((int) j + 1);

                         }
                 }
         }
         System.out.println("Attempt to solve: " + count);
         System.out.println("Your word is: ");

         for (char letters : letter) {
                 System.out.print(letters);

         }
      }
    }

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;


public class HangmanGuy extends JApplet
{
    public void paint (Graphics Page)
    {
                //gallows
                Page.drawLine(0,300,20,300);
                Page.drawLine(10,40,10,300);
                Page.drawLine(10,40,80,40);
                Page.drawLine(80,40,80,55);

                //torso
                Page.drawOval(50,55,50,55);
                Page.drawOval(50,100,50,100);
                //left arm and hand
                Page.drawLine(50,150,40,110);
                Page.drawLine(40,110, 45,100);
                Page.drawLine(40,110, 25,100);
                Page.drawLine(40,110, 25,115);


                //right arm and hand
                Page.drawLine(100,150,120,110);
                Page.drawLine(120,110, 115,95);
                Page.drawLine(120,110, 125,95);
                Page.drawLine(120,110, 135,115);

                //left  leg and foot
                Page.drawLine(80,200,100,250);
                Page.drawLine(100,250, 115,260);


                //right leg and foot
                Page.drawLine(75,200,60,250);
                Page.drawLine(60,250,45,260);

    }

}
```

Comment: You are misusing inheritance in a big way. That is not how it works or how you should even attempt it to work. You only use inheritance when you know a new class will fulfill the "is-a" relationship, and yours does not. Also, applets open from a browser.

Comment: This is the second time you've attempted this, even though it's previously being suggest that you should not mix console and GUI concepts.

Comment: Why bother making suggestions if he's just going to ignore them.

Comment: Sorry guys I was confused. So can I launch a Jframe with console output still and have the drawing in the jframe?

Comment: In general, you don't want to mix GUI's and consoles. You don't need to either. The exceptions include printing out debug statements, and using standard input and output, **in a background thread**, to communicate via sockets with other independent processes.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. Why should it.  Nothing is controlling it. Applets are suppose to be loaded and controlled by browsers;
2. Why are you mixing GUI and console paradigms?  User input from GUI's is suppose to come from UI components and controls, not the command line.

Start by taking a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

I'd recommend moving your UI to a `JFrame` instead, until you understand the basics of how to build a UI as applets bring there own issues which can stump you if you don't already have some background in how the UI works.

In fact.  Start with a `JPanel` and when you're ready, add it to an instance of `JFrame`.  When that works, you can try adding the panel to a `JApplet`